# How to initialize a SQL Server docker database with seed data?

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker

For a long time we had projects with DB init scripts for our Microsoft SQL Servers in steps such as:

1. Drop & create database
2. Create tables
3. Seed master data

I want to use Docker to create these databases locally, so I don't have to communicate with the dev database through a VPN. My problem is, the SQL Server Docker images don't seem to support any kind of seeding that other database images do.

I don't know how this would work, but I'd like to just point to a directory that has the seed scripts and bring up the db. I assume this would involve creating a custom Docker file, but how would the seeding take place?

Comment: If seeding consists of running insert statements, then you need a SQL script with those statements, and you need something to connect to the database and run them. That's usually SQLCMD.EXE. How did your existing init scripts work?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid open sql server management studio, open 01-drop-create.sql, hit Run, open 02-create-tables.sql , hit Run, etc. The files contain just simple sql commands, the schema is generated using the ssms wizard and the insert statements by hand